# Can The Free Storage Consume More Memory Left Over?

Tags: c++

```
int memory()
{
    int* p = new int[10000];
}
```

will this make 10000 ints unusable for things like local memory?
I don't know if it does.

Comment: Neither C++ knows. It's up to the OS. But the practical answer is no.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis: Well, C++ does put a limit the total amount of memory, bound by the number of potential values of a `char*`, so allocations like this must come out of that budget.

Comment: @MooingDuck True. But on systems with 64 bits of addressable space that limit is 18.4 exabytes which in practical terms is a very big so in practical terms no. There are other issues you will encounter long before you run out of addressable space.

Comment: @The Doge Master Your OS can use a combination of memory disk and potentially network storage to hold the data. Eventually you will run out of it but your OS will try to keep you going as long as it has physical resources to hold the data. But once you programs starts paging memory out to disk things start to get real slow (disk is 1000s of times slower than memory, network is 1000s of times slower than disk). Now if your OS/Compiler is smart and you allocate but **don't use the memory** then it technically does need to track it and can simply forget about it (or delay allocation until use).

Comment: The result of *repeatedly* calling the above function `memory()` will depend on the OS you are running on. On some systems you will run out of memory quickly. On other systems (that delay allocation until you try and use memory) then you would never run out of memory (as the variable p is leaked without ability for the application to use it). On some smart compilers the above statement can be removed by the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `new` is used to allocate the requested amount of memory(if available) to the object/array variable that you requested. In your case, the pointer `p`  will store the address to this allocated block of memory.

There's only a finite amount of memory that's available to you and so your program can only use from that amount of memory. This will vary from system to system but it will be finite. When you request for allocation of more memory than what can be allocated, the program will probably throw some exception like `std::bad_alloc` to indicate failure to allocate storage which if unhandled will crash your program.

> Does the memory allocated for the free store affect the whole
>   program's available memory?

**YES.**

The memory allocation in your program will be from heap storage (C++ knows if as *free store*). To answer your question, Yes, the allocated memory will reduce the amount of free memory available for other variables to use. There isn't an **infinite amount of memory** available for your program to use. So you might eventually run out of memory space once you have used up all the space available to you. However, you could also free up the memory once its work is done by using `delete` operator to free up the used memory space and make it available back again for use.

The memory space allocated to you will be implementation based. C++ itself knows nothing about the heap or how memory is allocated to it.

Comment: *The memory allocation will be from heap storage.* Better to say it comes from the freestore. The freestore is probably implemented with a heap, but it could also be Pixie dust and hamster wheels

Comment: @user4581301 Doesn't the `new` operator allocate memory dynamically from heap storage only?

Comment: @Abhishek "free store" is what the C++ language calls "the heap".

Comment: @eerorika ok. I have mentioned it now

Comment: It's also worth noting that the amount of "memory" available to your program is not necessarily limited by RAM. The OS can page "memory" to disk (or even network!) and reuse the RAM, specifically because C++ doesn't mention anything specific. That being said, you are bound by the number of potential values for `char*`, and also other practical OS-specific limitations.

Answer (score 3):

In practice: All storage uses memory (unless optimised away).

If you allocate 40000 bytes, and the operating system doesn't have 40000 bytes available (plus overhead that the free storage uses for managing the memory), then the operating system has to take actions to free some memory - typically by terminating your process, or some other process. This action may be delayed for when you actually use the memory rather than immediately upon allocation.

None of this is specified in the C++ language, and is an example of how an implementation of C++ language might behave. Other implementations may be different.

Answer (score 0):

In (portable) C++ you don't really know how much memory is there and what it can be used for.

`new` allocates from the free store and local variables are allocated in local storage. Then you have static storage and thread-local storage (and some other more "magic" things like the storage where exception objects are placed).

However for the C++ language all these memory locations come magically from those calls or syntax construct, each one with its specific semantic and for example you cannot know (portably) how much memory there is for each type and you cannot know if allocating memory of one type may lower the available amount of memory of another type. May be, may be not.

Consider even that for example for local storage you cannot know if you are running out of available local memory because the results of allocating too much local storage are simply undefined: think about it... you cannot know how much local memory there is but you cannot try to use more than that unknown amount because no check is done by the system and you jump straight into undefined behavior hell.

So for example for local storage the only practical advice is don't use "too much" of it.